# Revit IExternal Application Error- doesn't seems to run at all

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

Should we have something with the External application to properly register the event?

I also tried putting two breakpoints one inside the start module and other inside the Export module. 
the first responded and waited for me to continue and the next didn't respond(hope did not run the line)

Also,I had manually tried coping the addin file to the addin location to avoid any post build event error but still doesnt seem to work.

could you tell me what I am I doing wrong here.

Here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events;
using System.IO;

namespace UserDataSheet
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]

    [Regeneration(RegenerationOption.Manual)]

    public class UserDataSheetclass : IExternalApplication
    {
        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            try
            {
                // Register event. 
                application.ControlledApplication.DocumentOpened += new EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentOpenedEventArgs>(ExportLog);
                return Result.Succeeded;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Result.Failed;
            }
        }
        public void ExportLog(object sender, DocumentOpenedEventArgs args)
        {
            var doc = sender as Document;
            var isFamilyDoc = doc.IsFamilyDocument;

            // variables to use 
            string RevitUserName = "";
            DateTime OpenTime = new DateTime();
            string localUserName = "";
            string filename = "";
            string filepath = "";
            string content = "";

            if (isFamilyDoc == false)
            {

                var IsloggedIn = Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.IsLoggedIn;
                if (IsloggedIn == true )//&& doc.IsModelInCloud == true)
                {
                    // use variables
                    filepath = doc.PathName;
                    filename = doc.Title;
                    RevitUserName = doc.Application.Username;
                    OpenTime = DateTime.Now;
                    localUserName = System.Environment.MachineName;

                }
                content = string.Format("Date and time : {0} \n Revit UserName : {1} \n Local PC UserName : {2} \n FileName : {3} \n FilePath : {4} "
                    , OpenTime.ToString(), RevitUserName, localUserName, filename, filepath);
                TaskDialog.Show("Model Open Writer info", "user and file details : \n " + content);
            }
            var writefilepath = Path.GetTempPath();
            var Writefile = writefilepath + "//records.txt"; 
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Writefile, FileMode.Append);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
            writer.Write(content);
            writer.Close();
            File.OpenRead(Writefile);

        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can completely remove the `TransactionMode` and `RegenerationOption`. The latter is completely obsolete and does nothing at all anywhere whatsoever. The former is only useful when declaring an external command. It is useless and ignored in the context of an external application.

Secondly, to address your question: you can set a breakpoint in the beginning of `OnStartup`. If the breakpoint is not hit, your add-in is not being loaded at all.  Probably something is wrong with your add-in registration, e.g., in the add-in manifest `*.addin` file.

Go back to square one, i.e., work through the [getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) and the [developer guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2021/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_html) instructions on [registering and loading a Revit add-in](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2021/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Add_In_Integration_Add_in_Registration_html).

Answer (score 1):

If the breakpoint in `OnStartup` is hit, then your add-in is loading correctly, which means that the add-in manifest `*addin` file is OK. So, you do not need to worry about that. The `VisibilityMode` tag is not used for external applications, by the way.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thanks for the help. I have replied to your answer and made some edits to it later and hope you have not received the updates when you replied sorry about the confusion. The mistake was that I was extracting document from sender object instead of args(on the ExportLog function).I changed from "doc = sender as Document" to " doc = arg.Document" and it started to work fine. please see the edited post and help me so I can understand the problem better. Thanks for you help again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jeremy It worked

Firstly I apologies for adding this as answer( I don't know how to add codes in comment)

It worked when I deleted my Addin file and recreated it may be I had made some mistake in it.

meanwhile I have copied the following code from examples and used it,honestly I did't understand this line of the code.

```
"public void ExportLog(object sender, DocumentOpenedEventArgs args)"
```

can you point to a right source that explains this part. I have three questions here :

1. what object type is sender and args are they of type application?
2. How do I add a 3rd parameter to this method say I want the user to input a string to name the file the data is copied to.
3. Can I do this

   ```
          var newEvent  = new EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentOpenedEventArgs>(ExportLog);
   ```

instead of

```
application.ControlledApplication.DocumentOpened += new EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentOpenedEventArgs>(ExportLog);
```

why does all example use += is this to register the event every time a new instance of Revit is opened?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can see the class of `sender` yourself by setting a breakpoint at the beginning of `ExportLog` and looking in the debugger.
2. No, you cannot modify the signature of the event handler. It is predetermined by the Revit API.
3. Yes.

It sounds to me as if you might save some time and effort for yourself by learning a bit more about the basics of C# and .NET programming in general before continuing to tackle this task.